# Just Trying to Reinstall Grub2.04 on NVME

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

A relative newbie to this, but have used Ubuntu forever and want to start using it again.

I built a new computer recently, but made the partition for Ubuntu too small (15GB), so I created a new 100GB partition.

Now I am trying to reinstall Grub2.04.

I have tried using many techniques, including Grub-rescue, but they all seem to die and I cannot get Grub2.04 reinstalled.

The live USB that I am using has Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed on it. I am trying to reinstall Grub2.04 to once again use Ubuntu. It seems that I have Ubuntu installed on the 10GB partition, because I can access it using a SuperGrub2 USB.

Currently, I am getting an error "failed to get canonical path of `/cow'" when I run

```
sudo update-grub
```

It shouldn't be this hard to reinstall grub2. I will use a program or the terminal.

My NVME drives looks as follows when viewed by GParted:

- Partition 7 is where I have 100GB sitting with I believe my Ubuntu currently resides.
- Partitions 5 and 6 is where my Windows 10 resides.
- Partition 2 is where my Ubuntu used to reside (15GB).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

[image: GParted]

Comment: /cow is copy on write or your live installer. So you are trying to update live installer, not your install. For new users Boot-Repair is often easier. And if it does not work, you can post the link it gives to the Summary Report with details on your install. Add it to your Ubuntu live installer and be sure to boot it in UEFI boot mode. UEFI:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When I try running boot-repair, I get an error, "The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode."  Thus, I have to boot in EUFI boot mode.  One step at a time.  Thank you again.